# how can I get will_paginate working with ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, will-paginate, pagination

I have followed a few tutorials with no luck so far.  I am using ajax_pagination.  when I click the link for the second page, this is what the server log says:
    Started GET "/?page=2&*=1367953277288" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-07 14:05:49-0500

    Processing by AddressesController#index as JS
    Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "*"=>"1367953277288"}
    Address Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
    Rendered addresses/_addresses.html.erb (6.7ms)
    Rendered addresses/index.html.erb (8.4ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

so it appears that the request is correct, however nothing is changing on the page.  here is my code for the partial _addresses:

```
<%= ajax_loadzone do %>
<% @addresses.each do |address| %>
blah blah
<%end%>

<%= ajax_links :section_id => 'page' do %>
<%= will_paginate @addresses %>
<% end %>
```

controller:
    ajax_respond format, :section_id => "page", :render => "addresses"

index view:
     <%= ajax_section :id => 'page', :render => 'addresses' %>

this isn't all my code, but the pertinent bits.

Comment: I'm struggling on the same issue also, what resource that you used? Railscast mine, I follow the step but on that step on my application just can follow what Ryan Bates said. The different on my code and his code was on `live` being `on` (`live` was deprecated we know it), and js on `pagination.js` and mine on `application.js` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please CMIIW, I found a solution on my issue by setting up the jQuery pagination while re-render the section we want to render.

On `application.js`:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

$.fn.ajaxPagination = function() {
  this.on("click", function () {
    $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
    return false;
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".pagination a" ).ajaxPagination();
})
```

On `controller`:

```
def index
  @addresses = Address.pagination(params[:page])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @order_requests }
    format.js
  end
end
```

On `model`:

```
def self.pagination(page)
  paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => page)
end
```

On the let's say `index.js.erb`:

```
$('#page').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('addresses')) %>");
$(".pagination a").ajaxPagination();
```

And so on so far, please correct me if I am wrong, thank you.